# Partition merging with Gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, merge

I need to merge tow partitions with Gparted.

My main partition is: **/dev/sda6**
And i want to merge **/dev/sda5** partition into the main partition. sda5 is empty and unused partition. Please see the follwing screenshot:

[image]

Can someone instruct me how to do that? I'm afraid to lost the data in my main partition.

Comment: You mean your main partition is `sda6`, `sda5` is empty and unused, and you want to merge it into `sda6`, correct?

Comment: Yes. I fixed it. It was a typo.

Comment: "I'm afraid to lost the data in my main partition." you understand what a "backup" is?

Comment: It's not just about the data itself. I have a lot a configurations in my Ubuntu, configuration of development environment and many other things. Backup the data won't help in this case. I need to make an image of the entire operating system.

Comment: I don't think they understand "backup" --- changing a disk like this has a risk of losing data, if there's anything you absolutely must keep on the HD, make a copy of it first! And a compressed backup might be relatively small.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general approach you would be taking. You first have to boot into a live Ubuntu environment. To do that, burn an Ubuntu image on a CD/DVD/USB and boot from it as if you're installing Ubuntu but choose "Try Ubuntu" instead of "Install Ubuntu", then open GParted.

1. Right click on `sda5` and Delete. So you'll end up with `sda6`, `sda7`, followed by a big unallocated space.
2. Right click on `sda7` (swap) and Delete (if Delete is grayed out, choose Swapoff first). We'll recreate it later. So now you'll end up with `sda6` followed by a big unallocated space.
3. Right click on `sda6` and choose Resize/Move, and drag the right arrow to the right to fill up that space. Now you're "expanding" `sda6`, but don't expand it til the end. Leave 8 GBs in the end. Once done, click OK. Now you'll end up with a larger `sda6` and 8 GB of unallocated space.
4. Right click the unallocated space, choose New, then choose `linux-swap` as the filesystem. Click OK.
5. Now your table in GParted should show your merged (and large) `sda6`, followed by (I think it might be) `sda8` which is the `swap` partition. If you made any mistakes, close GParted and start over again. But if all looks good, click apply to apply all the changes we did. This might take sometime.
6. Once done, reboot and remove the CD/DVD/USB to go back into your Ubuntu. Open a terminal and type `sudo blkid /dev/sda8` (I'm assuming that `sda8` is the partition number for the new `swap` partition we created). Copy the `UUID=####` part. Type `sudo nano /etc/fstab`. Look for the line that looks like this:

   ```
   # swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
   UUID=###### none            swap    sw              0       0
   ```

   And change that UUID to the one you copied from the previous command. Save and close by Ctrl+X, Y, then Enter.
7. Reboot and you're done.